# С# Преобразовать String в DateTime

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Не получается преобразовать строку "**Wed, 29 Apr 2020 15:10:25 GMT**" в DateTime. Подскажите что я делаю не так.

```
 news.pubDate =DateTime.ParseExact(xUn.InnerText, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTime не умеет в GMT в принципе таймзоны совпадают, так что его можно просто выкинуть из парсинга:

```
"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'"
```

Будет работать.

Comment: Увы, не работает. Выкидывает ошибку System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid.

Comment: Специально собрал:
           var test = "Wed, 29 Apr 2020 15:10:25 GMT";
            var date = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", new DateTimeFormatInfo());
            Console.WriteLine(date.ToString());

Работает

Comment: Так. Разобрался немного. Первую дату конвертирует, а вторую... "Thu, 12 Mar 2020 9:38:53 GMT" Не хочет.

Comment: Подозреваю из-за девятки в HH. Что в таком случае делать?

Comment: Бум! Я просто использовал news.pubDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strr); и всё заработало, как надо.